# Create a pie chart from amount/category pairs

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc

From a table like

```
Amount | Category
  2        A
  1        B
  5        A
```

how to create a pie chart with one sector per category found in the second colum and the summed up values for each category?
In this example two pies: A=7, B=1

There is an answer to a similar question for Excel that uses a pivot table: [Create a pie chart from distinct values in one column by grouping data in Excel](https://superuser.com/q/329334/96128).

Is there an easier way in libreoffice?

How to create a pivot table for this scenario? When selecting both columns, the menu `Data - Pivot Table - Create` is not available ([Documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Creating_Pivot_Tables)).